# Multi Data Trigger In Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am attempting to allow click on my button ONLY if the two text fields are not null.  However, I am getting the compile error of

> Type multi-data trigger not found

Below is my syntax, how should I change it so it executes as desired?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>  
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"  
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" >
<ContentPage.Content>  
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="30" Spacing="40">  
        <BoxView HeightRequest="10"/>  
        <Frame BackgroundColor="#BF043055" HasShadow="False">  
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="10">  
                <Entry x:Name="Email" Text="{Binding Email}" Placeholder="Email"   
                       PlaceholderColor="Red" HeightRequest="50"   
                       Keyboard="Email" TextColor="Black" />
                <Entry x:Name="Password" Text="{Binding Password}" Placeholder="Password"   
                       PlaceholderColor="Red" HeightRequest="50"   
                       IsPassword="True" TextColor="Black" />  
                </StackLayout>  
        </Frame>  
        <Button x:Name="loginbutton" Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}" Text="Login" TextColor="White"  
                FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Large" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  
                BackgroundColor="#088da5" > 
                <Button.Style>
                  <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                      <Style.Triggers>
                          <MultiDataTrigger>
                              <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                 <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=Email, Path=Text.Length, Mode=OneWay}" Value="0"/>
                                 <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=Password, Path=Text.Length, Mode=OneWay}" Value="0"/>
                              </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                              <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                         </MultiDataTrigger>
                     </Style.Triggers>
                  </Style>
                </Button.Style>
        </Button>
    </StackLayout>  
</ContentPage.Content>  
</ContentPage>
```

**EDIT**
I edited my syntax to the below but I am getting a compile error of:

> No property, bindable property, or event found for 'ElementName', or mismatching type between value and property.

```
            <Button x:Name="loginbutton" Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}" Text="Login" TextColor="White"  
                FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Large" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  
                BackgroundColor="#088da5" > 
                <Button.Style>
                  <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                      <Style.Triggers>
                          <MultiTrigger TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                              <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                 <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=Email, Path=Text.Length, Mode=OneWay}" Value="0"/>
                                 <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=Password, Path=Text.Length, Mode=OneWay}" Value="0"/>
                              </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                              <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                         </MultiTrigger>
                     </Style.Triggers>
                  </Style>
                </Button.Style>
        </Button>
```

Comment: Isn't `MultiDataTrigger` supposed to be just `MultiTrigger`?

Comment: Change `ElementName` to `Source`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MultiDataTrigger` is specific to WPF. Xamarin uses `MultiTrigger`, which essentially does the same thing. Have a look through [this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/triggers-in-xamarin-forms/) to see how to implement Triggers in Xamarin Forms.

Comment: Changing it to MultiTrigger gives me a compile error of 'TargetType' is required to use MultiTrigger

Comment: Look in the blog post I linked, under the section **Multi Triggers**. You have **two** sections where you must define the `TargetType`: before the `Style` and at the beginning of `Style`.